# Trouble with multiplying array elements

Tags: c#

Basically i'm trying to multiply each element of the first array with each element of the second array and then store it all at the end as a total. I'm pretty new to coding so just trying to learn and this one really has me stuck. This is the example of what it should eventually do.

```
ExampleArray1 = 5,6,7,8 
ExampleArray2 = 2,3,4

(5*2)+(5*3)+(5*4) + (6*2)+(6*3)+(6*4) + (7*2)+(7*3)+(7*4) + (8*2)+(8*3)+(8*4) = 234
```

My code

```
        int[] firstArray = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        int[] secondArray = { 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] thirdArray = new int[firstArray.Length * secondArray.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
            {
                thirdArray[i * firstArray.Length + j] = firstArray[i] * secondArray[j];
                Console.WriteLine(thirdArray[i * firstArray.Length + j]);
            }
```

Comment: I'm new to this site so wasn't sure what title i should put honestly just looking for some help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Check out [ask] for tips on how to write a question that will attract upvotes and quality answers. Also take the [tour].

Comment: So is the requirment to compute the sum? Because you seem to be generating a matrix instead. The assignment is not clear to me. What is the third array for?

Comment: think about the type of object you need for the answer you are looking for. You thought since you are adding arrays you need an array.. but that is overthinking. If you are looking for a number, then it should be an int, or a long, depending on size, not an array.

Comment: Yeah i need to times each element of array 1 with each element of array 2 and write the sum to the console. I used this code above from another site and it kind of worked as it showed me the answer to all of these in the console window (5*2)+(5*3)+(5*4) + (6*2)+(6*3)+(6*4) + (7*2)+(7*3)+(7*4) but not (8*2)+(8*3)+(8*4) or the sum.

Comment: Interesting that the OP's first thought was to do it the way a functional programmer might, or essentially the way LINQ would do it. However for a beginning c# programmer I'm pretty sure you're expected to do it with the loop + accumulator approach in the accepted answer.

Comment: It's because i got the code from a different site my mind went blank at first and now after looking at the answer provided i don't understand why i didn't see what i had to do originally.

Comment: Do you actually need that intermediate array? Are you aware that your final total will be the same as adding each array up and then multiplying them together? ie `(5+6+7+8)*(2+3+4)=234`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a third array, you can just sum the results

```
var total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
   {
      total += (firstArray[i] * secondArray[j]);
   }
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

However you forgot to minus one form the length, in the third array index.

i.e  to get the index you need `i * (firstArray.Length - 1) + j`

```
int[] thirdArray = new int[firstArray.Length * secondArray.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
   {
      thirdArray[i * (firstArray.Length - 1) + j] = firstArray[i] * secondArray[j];
   }
Console.WriteLine(thirdArray.Sum());
```

Comment: Thanks i had a feeling i was over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply some basic algebra to simplify this:

```
var total = 0;
var array1Total = 0;
var array2Total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.Length; i++)
{
    array1Total += firstArray[i];
}

for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.Length; j++)
{
    array2Total += secondArray[j];
}
total = array1Total * array2Total;
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

The reason is that if you expand (x0+x1+x2+x3...)*(y0+y1+y2+...) then you can see that you will multiply x0 by each of the y, then multiply x1 by each of the y, and so on. So you'll get each of the elements in the first brackets multiplied by each of the elements in the second brackets.

While this may not seem much different it will be considerably better for large arrays. if the length of your arrays are m and n then by the nested loops method you'll have m*n loop iterations. With the above technique you will have m+n. For small values this isn't a big deal. If you have arrays of thousands of items then the above will be significantly faster.

Of course, there is an even easier way to do the above:

```
var total = firstArray.Sum()*secondArray.Sum();
```

Comment: Nice logical approach

Comment: Its always nice to see maths you learnt at school making itself useful outside of those classes. :)

Comment: also too `firstArray.Sum() * secondArray.Sum();`

Comment: Yeah, I considered using linq but decided to stick with the loops as the original. You are right though that I should probably include that in the answer.